# Forward declaration of member struct

Tags: c++, class, struct

I want to write such a code, but it doesn't work:

```
struct ast;
struct parser;

struct parser
{
    struct node
    {
        node *parent;
    };

    ast build_ast() //here we want to use object of ast tyoe
    {
        node *ret = new node;
        return ast(ret);
    }
}; 

struct ast
{
    parser::node *root; //here we try to access member struct of y
    ast(parser::node *rt):root(rt){}
};
```

The problem is that I try to create in parser an object of incomplete type. If I swap implementations of structures, the problem is that I try to access member struct of incomplete type. Obviously, I can solve this problem, by making node an independent structure, but that seems bad, because I may want to have other node types in my program.
The question is: can I somehow make a forward declaration of node struct outside the parser struct? For example:

```
struct ast;
struct parser;
struct parser::node; //making a forward declaration of member struct
```

If this cannot be done, what are the ways to solve the conflict?

Comment: You never forward declared `node`.

Comment: just declare the ast build_ast() function in the struct and define it later, after struct ast.

Comment: Put the declaration and definition of classes in their respective headers, and the implementation of member functions in the `.cpp` file where you have to include the appropriate headers also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to defer the definition of `build_ast` until `ast` is a complete type:

```
inline ast build_ast(); //here we want to use object of ast type
```

<sub>`inline` is here to make this declaration functionally identical to what you had in example. You may want to remove it and move `build_ast` to an implementation file</sub>

Outside of the struct definition:

```
ast parser::build_ast()
{
    node *ret = new node;
    return ast(ret);
}
```

To forward-declare `node`, you need to do this within `parser` definition. In other words, you cannot forward-declare an inner class without defining the outer.

```
struct parser
{
    struct node;
    // ...
};
```

You can then proceed with a definition:

```
struct parser::node
{
    node *parent;
};
```